# Sharepoint 2010: Saving content of a textbox back to a variable of a visual web-part

Tags: visual-web-part, visual-studio-2012

not sure if this is even possible. What I'm trying to do is create a visual web-part for SharePoint 2010 (using Visual Studio 2013) that will allow the user to add the web-part to a page then add data to a text box, the data is then saved with the web-parts variables.

What I've tried so far is adding a button to the page that when clicked will set the variable but this doesn't seem to work as the page refreshes, which resets the content in the text-boxes to the stored data before the code can override it.

Does anyone know if this is even possible? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I've hit a brick wall. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by "webpart variable". When you click a button that causes a postback(the pages refreshes), you maybe reset your value in the textbox. What you can do is to set your textbox value only if it is not a postback:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
      myTextBox.Text = GetTheValue();
  }
}
```

If it isn't what the problem is, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry by webpart variable I was talking about the properties of the webpart 

`        [WebBrowsable(true),
         Category("Accordion Data"),
         Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
         WebDisplayName("Section 1 Title")]
        public String Section01Title { get; set; }
`
What I'm trying to do is when my button is clicked set the string 'Section01Title' to what is entered in a textbox. I've tried the way you mentioned (Section01Title = txtBox.Text) but unfortunately this didn't work.

Comment: sorry the code I pasted made that look like a really messy response

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is wanting it I managed to figure it out.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Section01Title = txtTitle01.Text;
        Section01Content = txtContent01.Text;
        this.SetPersonalizationDirty();
    }
```

I was missing the "this.SetPersonalizationDirty();" line after setting the Sharepoint properties. Apparently this tells the web-part to save back to Sharepoint (from what I understand)